# Jaccard Similarity in Lucene

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval, similarity

I need to calculate the similarity of a query and document in Lucene using Jaccard similarity over n-grams. As Jaccard similarity is is a very common measure in IR, I expected to find a Lucene implementation for it, but I couldn't.

Is anyone aware of such an implementation?

Answer (score 2):

The only implementation I'm aware of that can be easily integrated with Lucene is the one from LingPipe (please note that it's free only for non-commercial/research usage). [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110804075030/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2011/01/02/processing-tweets-with-lingpipe-3-near-duplicate-detection-and-evaluation) is a blog post showing how to use it in LingPipe. A detailed explanation on how to connect both libraries is available on LingPipe website and in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0615204252).

I haven't evaluated however, if it wouldn't be easier (also from license point of view) to integrate some other implementation on your own -- it's just a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this library http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/ you find much more similarity functions. But 
I will recommend you to use SoftTFIDF from http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/, it has the best precision/recall according "A Comparison of String Distance Metrics for Name-Matching Tasks". William W. Cohen and others.